# Detecting recursion in a C file with Python

Tags: python, c, regex, parsing

I need to detect direct and indirect recursion in a rather large (5-15,000) set of C (not C++) files.

The files are already preprocessed.

The code is pretty "old school" for safety reasons so no fancy things like function pointers in there, only functions that pass variables about and some function-macros that do the same.

The most natural way to detect recursion is to make a directed call-graph, considering each function a node with an edge going to all the other functions that it calls. If the graph has any cycles, then we have recursion.

A regex to find function calls is trivial to make but I also need to know which function did the calling.

PyCParser was nice but it complains about a lot of things such as variables that are not defined or typedefs where the source type is not defined or defined in a different file which are completely irrelevant in my use-case. The project uses a custom dependency management system so some includes and the such are added automatically so I would need PyCParser to not care about *anything* other than `FuncCall` and `FuncDef` nodes and I don't think there is a way to limit the parsing process itself to just that.

I would rather not implement a parser as there i do not exactly have the time to learn how to do that in python and then implement the solution.

Back to the issue, how would I go about parsing the functions in a C file? Basically getting a dict with strings(names of functions defined in the file) as the keys, and lists of strings(the functions called by each function) as the values? A regex seems to be the most natural solution.

Using python is not optional sadly.

Comment: What's the output you're looking for ? A function that would write to `stdout` something like `Warning: <function_name> is recursive !` ?

Comment: create a graph indicating which function calls which functions and search for cycles.

Comment: @IMCoins I detalied that in the last paragraph. :) I would like a dict of who calls who, I have the part about detecting cycles in a graph-like dict implemented and functional already.

Comment: C cannot be parsed without knowing which identifiers are types, so your "custom dependency management system" is a hard block.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I already said that that's what I'm doing. :/ Now how do I go about parsing the C file?

Comment: He answered to my question.

Comment: @melpomene I'm not looking for a full C parser, that was my whole point. I just need to detect the full function body following a function header basically.

Comment: You also need to detect function calls, which is impossible if you don't know your type names.

Comment: a parser like pycparser works fine on a preprocessed code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have explained why it does not in my case though.

Comment: next time I'll read your post :) pycparser works fine when the file is fully preprocessed. I remember it tries to preprocess the file, but that part should be skipped, because you'd have to provide all include locations... better provide an already preprocessed file, and in that case, you get all the info. I¨heard that `clang` is very good as well. Seems to have a python binding.

Comment: To elaborate on my comment, consider `A ( B ); ( C ) ( D );`, How many function calls is this?

Comment: @melpomene but if you can make a list of all existing functions of the project, then you just have to find the function words in the function bodies. If we find the word, then it's either a call or a reference-taking for a function pointer, which is potentially recursion (or we can look for the word+parenthese). For that you need a token parser, not necessarily too elaborate.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thats actually a pretty damn nice idea. I almost called it a hack but I think it's too nice and general to actually be called a hack. I do not need to add functions in the standard library or the used frameworks as nodes in the call graph since obviously there wont be circular recursion between a framework/standard library and a function defined in the current project.

Comment: 1) run the executable under gdb; hit ^C; hit c; repeat this a few times. Now you know where your program spends its time. 2) gprof

Comment: @joop this is not possible in this kind of project magnitude unfortunately.  The compilation can easily go over 2 hours from start to finish on an average project.

Comment: I expect a compiler will read the sources faster than your Python-tool. (mine reads nearly 100MB/sec) And it will even create executable code, too! And gprof will create a (reduced) call-graph for you, based on sampling the instruction pointer. Any significant recursion will show up. But if you want static analisys: just produce the call-graph. Beware of conditioal compilation/execution and dead code!

Comment: ` would rather not implement a parser ...` I am afraid you'll need one, you at least need to find the function calls. Maybe you could use yacc/flex and rip out the tables and generate Python code based on these tables?

Comment: @joop As I said, I do not exactly have the time to learn how to make a parser in python. I know whar a grammar, AST, etc. is but I have never used them for something like this. 
Unless the problem becomes trivial using those im not sure it is possible.

Comment: If you fully documented the functions using (for instance: doxygen) then the tool (for instance: doxygen) can produce the complete call graph for you.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use `objdump` on your compiled code then parse the generated assembly to build your graph?

test1.c file:

```
extern void test2();

void test1()
{
   test2();
}
```

test2.c file:

```
extern void test1();

void test2()
{
   test1();
}


int main()
{
   test2();
}
```

now build it:

```
gcc -g test1.c test2.c -o myprog
```

now disassemble

```
objdump -d myprog > myprog.asm
```

Lookup all functions calls with a couple of simple regexes while memorizing the context you're on. A sample of the disassembly shows you how easy it should be:

```
00401630 <_test1>:
  401630:   55                      push   %ebp
  401631:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  401633:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  401636:   e8 05 00 00 00          call   401640 <_test2>
  40163b:   c9                      leave  
  40163c:   c3                      ret    
  40163d:   90                      nop
  40163e:   90                      nop
  40163f:   90                      nop

00401640 <_test2>:
  401640:   55                      push   %ebp
  401641:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  401643:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  401646:   e8 e5 ff ff ff          call   401630 <_test1>
  40164b:   c9                      leave  
  40164c:   c3                      ret
```

then use python to postprocess your disassembly and build a dictionary of function=>calls:

```
import re
import collections

calldict = collections.defaultdict(set)

callre = re.compile(".*\scall\s+.*<(.*)>")
funcre = re.compile("[0-9a-f]+\s<(.*)>:")

current_function = ""

with open("myprog.asm") as f:
    for l in f:
        m = funcre.match(l)
        if m:
            current_function = m.group(1)
        else:
            m = callre.search(l)
            if m:
                called = m.group(1)
                calldict[current_function].add(called)
```

I didn't write the full graph search, but you can detect "ping-pong" recursion with a simple code like:

```
for function,called_set in calldict.items():
    for called in called_set:
        callset = calldict.get(called)
        if callset and function in callset:
            print(function,called)
```

which gives me:

```
_test2 _test1
_test1 _test2
```

this symbol/asm analysis technique is also used in [callcatcher](http://www.skynet.ie/~caolan/Packages/callcatcher.html) to detect unused C functions (which can be done very easily here as well by checking keys that aren't in any sets, with a bit of filtering of compiler symbols)

Comment: The OP **needs** to use Python. I quote : `Using python is not optional sadly.`.

Comment: and of course post-processing MUST be done in python :)

Comment: I admire your way of solving this problem. :) (even though we do not know if the file could be pre-processed this way)

Comment: thank you. Combining compiler tools & python is usually very efficient.

Comment: I would have tried something different at first. Manually parsing the c file since it's "basic C code". But this might take a little while to process over 15.000 c files to read as OP said.

Comment: @IMCoins That's true. Simple preprocessing of the whole project takes about 45-60 minutes on an intel 6700, compilation takes easily as long too, maybe even more.