# Finding functions using a static string in .rodata section

Tags: c, linux, gcc, elf

For example I have an object file `x.o`, without the source code. The file is an ELF file compiled on Linux.

In `.rodata` section of the file, there's a string `my-string` (can be viewed by `readelf -p .rodata x.o`).

Is there any way that we can know which functions in object file is using that string?

Comment: I've written an answer based on disassembly to find recursion (functions which use functions): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175624/detecting-recursion-in-a-c-file-with-python/49176138#49176138

Comment: the problem is that the linker hasn't inserted the symbols. Can't you work on the actual executable?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this object file is actually a shared library. So there is no executable file.

Comment: shared library is good. Make it  `.so` then. Have you tried `objdump -d x.so` and see if you see `mystring` in there?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've already tried objdump, but could not see the string in there.